# using unsecured references in SharePoint Online Sites

Tags: sharepoint-online

Does Sharepoint (365) block sites that don't have "https"? I've tried using external stylesheets and embedding code that are unsecured (http), but they didn't work. Anyone know more about this?

Answer (score 1):

Check F12 Dev tools. Your browser blocks mixed content.

For all Browsers:
https://help.optimizely.com/hc/en-us/articles/204602997-Troubleshooting-Compatibility-mode-warning-and-mixed-content-in-the-Editor

You can serve Stylesheets from other HTTPS sites, but not .woff Font files.